# Socket Handle Read Is never read In Ns3

Tags: c++, sockets, debugging, simulation, handle

I stayed many days to find where the error is and I'm stuck.Can anyone help me please.

MY application is a clustering program in NS3 that was written from one else and free to anyone.
The program is run and no errors and print messages but always the number of neighbors in every Cluster Head CH is zero, this mean that the hellow messages are not reach every node and every node consider itself as cluster head because it dosn't see any neighbor node!. every node (vehicle) has two sockets one for send data **m_socket** and one for listening **m_socketlistening**, the code is:

```
if (!m_socket)
 {
    //  TypeId::LookupByName ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory
    
    TypeId m_tid = TypeId::LookupByName("ns3::UdpSocketFactory");
    //m_socket = Socket::CreateSocket(GetNode() , TypeId::LookupByName("ns3::UdpSocketFactory"));
    m_socket = Socket::CreateSocket(GetNode(), m_tid);
    // i added the down line

  // InetSocketAddress remote = InetSocketAddress(Ipv4Address::GetBroadcast(),80);

    if (Inet6SocketAddress::IsMatchingType(m_peer)) 
    {
        m_socket->Bind6();
    } 
    else if (InetSocketAddress::IsMatchingType(m_peer)
            || PacketSocketAddress::IsMatchingType(m_peer))
    {
         
        m_socket->Bind();
    }
   

    m_socket->SetAllowBroadcast(true);
    m_socket->ShutdownRecv();
    
     m_socket->SetConnectCallback(
     MakeCallback(&V2vControlClient::ConnectionSucceeded, this),
     MakeCallback(&V2vControlClient::ConnectionFailed, this));
     //m_socket->Connect(Ipv4Address::GetBroadcast());
     m_socket->Connect(m_peer);

}
```

now this is a part pf the listening socket creation

```
if (!m_socketListening)
{

NS_LOG_UNCOND("\n ...creating socket muhsen...");
    m_socketListening = Socket::CreateSocket(GetNode(), m_tidListening);
    m_socketListening->Bind(m_peerListening);
    m_socketListening->Listen();
    m_socketListening->ShutdownSend();
    if (addressUtils::IsMulticast(m_peerListening)) 
    {
        Ptr<UdpSocket> udpSocket = DynamicCast<UdpSocket>(m_socketListening);
        if (udpSocket)
        {   
            // equivalent to setsockopt (MCAST_JOIN_GROUP)
            udpSocket->MulticastJoinGroup(0, m_peerListening);
        } 
      else 
        {
            NS_FATAL_ERROR("Error: joining multicast on a non-UDP socket");
        }
    }
}



m_socketListening->SetRecvCallback(MakeCallback(&V2vControlClient::HandleRead, this));
m_socketListening->SetAcceptCallback(
        MakeNullCallback<bool, Ptr<Socket>, const Address &>(),
        MakeCallback(&V2vControlClient::HandleAccept, this));
m_socketListening->SetCloseCallbacks(
        MakeCallback(&V2vControlClient::HandlePeerClose, this),
        MakeCallback(&V2vControlClient::HandlePeerError, this));

   



void  V2vControlClient::HandleRead (Ptr<Socket> socket)
{

NS_LOG_UNCOND("\n this message is never executed..");


NS_LOG_FUNCTION (this << socket);
Ptr<Packet> packet;
Address from;

while ((packet = socket->RecvFrom(from)))
   {
    if (packet->GetSize() == 0) 
    { //EOF
        break;
    }
```

When i run the application the first statement after the HandleRead Function which is
NS_LOG_UNCOND("\n this message is never executed..");
is never printed when run the program, this means that the handle read ***is never executed***.
**Any help is very appreciate**!

Comment: I would guess that you are supposed to set callbacks on `m_socketListening` **before** calling `Listen`. I would further guess that a listening socket would generate an accept callback but never a recv callback.

Comment: Thank very much for your reply. But i did what you suggest, I put the listen statement after callback and nothing changed, I din't understand the second suggestion, do you say that the listening socket should not have accept callbak?. I tried to cancel setacceptcallback and nothing changed, what is the best way to set the listen socket code?.  Also i made a trace for the packet is is sent from all layers in the source node and i noticed it is recived by the netdevice mac layer, so why the handle read is not invoked, is the local address is right, thank you very much for your help

Comment: I say that the listening socket would likely fire Accept callback but not Recv callback. And `HandleRead` is in fact the recv callback, so it's not surprising it's not being called. I'm not familiar with the library you are using, but "normal" sockets work like this. You have a listening socket. When an incoming connection arrives, you call Accept on that socket - that returns another socket representing this particular connection. Then you read and write on that accepted socket, while the listening socket continues to listen for more connections.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and patience because i have about month didn't have solution. First are your familiar with NS3 simulator, this is an application in ns3, also what I understand from you that you think that the listening socket is on server, no. i  have for example 5 nodes move (wifi and have mobility) and every node have two sockets one for sendind and the other just for listening for broadcast. so the listening socket is listen for the beacon messages. Could you please suggest in code what i have to do if you have experience in NS3. Many thanks to you.

Comment: Listening socket is for accepting incoming connections. Whether you call the program that listens and accepts connections a "server" or something else is irrelevant. No, I'm not familiar with NS3, never heard of it before.

Comment: Thanks alot for your patience and help. best regards